# Laravel Controller saying undefined Request, Any error here?

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a laravel project but some part of my codes is returning an error of undefined request
Seems like i forgot something or ..

---

Here is a snip
[Of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXyRC.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code as text to your question rather than using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with how you defined Request Parameter in your function, It should be like

---

```
public function insertrecord(Request $request) {}
```

---

Now you can proceed... Hope this helps..

Comment: and make sure you have:  use Illuminate\Http\Request; in the top of your file